# MSSQL Case denoted by an integer returns a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an issue with my SELECT statement in SSRS.
  I want to use an integer to return strings values.

I tried it with this SELECT clause:

```
SELECT CASE @param = '1' THEN value like '__%' ELSE value like ' '
```

But it doesn't work, so I tried to use this one instead:

```
WHERE
((@param = '1' AND value like '__%') OR (@param = '0' AND value = '%'))
```

The expected result is: When the case is "1" SELECT should return only values which are not ' '
   When the case is "0" SELECT should return all values = ' ' + '__%'

Thank you for your help

Comment: The `Where` option is the way to go - but why are you comparing the interger `@param` to a string? Also, please [edit] your question to include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your case condition is wrong formatted. You missed WHEN and END .It should be like that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @param = '1' THEN value like '__%' ELSE value like ' ' END
```

**EDIT** : As much as I understand you want to see Value if the @param='1' and if not the result will be '__%'. If yes this following `CASE` usage should be correct:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @param = '1' THEN value ELSE value= '__%'  END
```

Comment: `CASE` expressions need to return a scalar value and in SQL Server, predicates do not produce such values. You can't have predicates as the expressions in your `THEN` or `ELSE` clauses.

Comment: You are right, honestly I didn't notice the LIKE . I just checked missing pieces only. I will try to be more careful. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it my self condition is
((@column = '1' AND column like '__%') OR (@column = '0'AND column like '_%'))

Comment: Do you understand that underscore is a wildcard for any character? Your logic means you are simply testing for a minimum length. Why so complicated, hard-to-read, easy-to-misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
((@param = '1' AND value != '') OR (@param = '0'))
```

just try this